# Changing the directory of the shell through a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, shell, directory

I'm trying to write a simple C++ program to execute Linux commands. I'm stuck at changing the directories (commands like `chdir` and `cd` don't work). This is what I have so far:

```
system("echo -n '1. Current Directory is '; pwd");
system("chdir Desktop");
```

Comment: System spawns a new shell. So by the time it closes the changed directory has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, if you want to change the directory (i.e. `cd`, that is [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) ...) of the shell which has invoked your program. So `cd` has to be a [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) builtin.

The reason is that `chdir` affects only the calling process (which would be your C program) not the parent process. Each process has its own current directory. See also [getcwd(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

If you call [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) it will [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a new shell and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) `/bin/sh -c` so only the forked shell can change its current directory.

You need to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Perhaps you want to call `chdir` directly inside your C program. This will affect the current process and all future child processes (including those started with `system` or `popen` library functions inside your C code) till their termination or some further call to `chdir`. But it won't affect the shell in your terminal (where you started your C program).

Comment: so,you mean this is not possible at all?

Comment: Yes, I just explained why it is not possible. Please read the references.