# How shell commands execute

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am a newbee and looking for some info.

Thanks in advance.

1. What is difference between echo "Hello World!" and a c-program which prints "Hello World!" using printf.
2. How do shell commands get executed. For example if I give `ls` it lists all the files in the directory. Is there executable binary which is run when we enter `ls` in shell.

Please let me know if you guys have any links or source to get this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main types of "commands" that the shell can execute. Built-in commands are executed by the shell itself - no new program is started. Simply typing `echo` in a shell prompt is an example of such a built-in command.

On the other hand, other commands execute external programs (also called binaries) - and `ls` is an example of this kind of command.

So, if you run `echo` in a shell, it's executed by the shell itself, but if you write a C program that performs the same action, it wil be run as an external program. As a matter of fact, most Linux systems come with such a binary, located at `/bin/echo`.

Why does it sometimes make sense to have both a built-in command and a program to accomplish the same task? Built-in commands are faster to execute as there is some cost involved in running an external program. But built-ins have some drawbacks, too: they can't be too complex as this would make the shell big and slow; they can not be upgraded separately from the shell and from each other; finally, there are situations where an external program which is not your shell would like to run an application: it can run external programs but it can't execute shell built-ins directly since it's not the shell. So sometimes it makes sense to have it both ways. Apart from `echo`, `time` is another example of this double approach.

Comment: And just to add on to this good explanation, the actual binary used when invoking `ls` (or any other binary for that matter) is returned by `which ls`. And.. to get to know more information on the binaries, you always have the `man ls`.

Comment: in bash, `type ls` makes more sense than `which ls`

Comment: Thanks Michal for explaining :D

Comment: I believe that `cd` is a more useful example of shell builtin than `echo`. Because `cd` *has to be* a builtin. But `echo`  could be `/bin/echo` in *some* shells. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21580827/841108)

Answer (score 0):

The shell is just a user level way of interacting with the operating system, or the kernel.  That's one of the reasons it's called a *shell*.  The shell itself (`sh`, `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`, etc...) is essentially just a binary the operating system executes to allow you to execute other binaries.

It generally gives a lot of other functionality though like built in functions (`echo`, `fg`, `jobs`, etc...), an interpreted language (`for x in ...`, `if then`, etc...), command history, and so on...

So, any text entered into the shell (like `echo`), the binary (or process) interprets and runs the corresponding functions in its code.  Built in functions (like `echo`) don't need to create a new process, but if the text is interpreted as a request to execute a binary (`vim`, `emacs`, `gcc`, `test`, `true`, `false`, etc...) the shell will create a new process for it (unless you prefix it with`exec`), and execute it.

So, `echo "Hello World!` just runs code in the shell (process).  A `printf("Hello World!")` would be in seperate binary that the shell would create a new process for (`fork`), and have the operating system execute (`exec`).