# How can I change bash directory from C++ program?

Tags: c++, bash

I have a C++ program which finally prints a directory path according to an index input by a user.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {

    //SUB-ROUTINE: print directory paths with index, using "complex" algorithm
    //                (so an external command rather than a bash function)
    //                (this sub-routine gives choose-able options to a user)
    //                (please note this sub-routine includes `cout`)

    unsigned index;
    cout << "Input index: ";
    cin >> index;

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            cout << "/home/user/foo"; break;
        case 1:
            cout << "/home/user/bar"; break;
        default:
            cout << "/home/user";
    }

}
```

But you can't write in bash

```
cd $(a.out)
```

because of many reasons. One reason is that `a.out` has more outputs than just the resulting directory path.

In this context, how can I change the current directory of the calling process (`bash`)? Linux-specific way is ok. Though, of course, outputting the directory path into a file (in ramdisk) and read it from bash can realize what I want, I don't think that is a wise way.

---

Related: [Changing the directory of the shell through a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580787/changing-the-directory-of-the-shell-through-a-c-program)

---

Supplement:

If I rewrite the C++ program as

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc == 1) {

        //print directory paths with index

    } else {

        unsigned index = atoi(argv[1]);

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                cout << "/home/user/foo"; break;
            case 1:
                cout << "/home/user/bar"; break;
            default:
                cout << "/home/user";
        }

    }

}
```

, then I can write

```
./a.out
reply -p "Input index: "
cd $(a.out $REPLY)
```

but this is not straightforward (dirty) and makes the program more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

It's a bit heavy weight but you can use

```
cd $(a.out | awk '{print $NF}')
```

#### Option 2

Change the line

```
cout << "Input index: ";
```

to

```
cout << "Input index: \n";
```

and then use

```
cd $(a.out | tail -1)
```

#### Option 3

Remove the line

```
cout << "Input index: ";
```

altogether and use:

```
cd $(a.out)
```

#### Option 4

Print the selected directory with some distinct token(s) and use that to filter the output.

Example:

```
std::cout << "==== " << "/home/user/foo" << std::endl;
break;
```

Then, in `bash`, you can use:

```
cd $(a.out | grep '====' | awk '{print $2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But please note the comment of my C++ program `//print directory paths with index`. I'm sorry that my intention was not clear to you, but this comment represents a sub-routine. What I want to do is 1. print directory list with index (i.e. give choosable options to a user), 2. make a user input an index with prompt, 3. print the directory which corresponds to the index. Even with your solution, `$(a.out)` includes the output of the first step. Pseudo code of the first step: `for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) { cout << i << " " << dir_list[i] << "\n"; }`

Comment: @ynn, see the updated answer. You can use that for the use case you described in your comment.

Comment: Thank you. It works well and doesn't abuse `cerr`. By the way, isn't there any more natural way which makes the C++ program interact with the calling process? For example, can't I define shell variable of the calling shell and use it after the program exits? Pseudo code: `int main() { /* ... */ define_shell_var("cd_target", selected_directory); }` and `./a.out && cd ${cd_target}`.

Comment: @ynn, I don't think you can. There are probably mane reasons why you are not allowed to do that. I am not familiar with the subject to give you a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I understand. Thinking twice, now it seems really dangerous if you can change the value of the shell variable. I'm obliged to you.

Comment: You can only change environment (exported) variables in your own process and in child processes, not in the parent process.  Environment variables are *copied* to child processes.  Other variables that are not exported are not visible outside the process.

Answer (score -1):

I've just found the answer.

According to `man bash`,

> Command Substitution
>
> (snip)
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and  replacing the command substitution **with the standard output** of the command

So one can replace all of `cout` with `cerr` other than the final one (with `using std::cerr;`).

Comment: Use of `cerr` should be reserved for printing error messages. Using it to print user input prompts is an abuse of the idea. This is my opinion, of course.

Comment: @RSahu I really agree with you, generally. I'd like to avoid such a solution if there is another simple solution.